# Left align the array conditional

Tags: arrays

The conditional appears in the center of the line, I would like to left align the conditional.  I have tried quite a few things and ultimately settled on the following.  Is there a way to left align the entire conditional for the whole line so it is aligned with more text?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, array}

\begin{document}

$M( \langle U_1, \dots, U_n \rangle ) \to \langle Y_1, \dots, Y_n \rangle $ where

\[
Y_i = 

\begin{cases}

1 & \text{if }  U_i \in \Sigma \\

0 & \text{if }  U_i \notin \Sigma \\

\end{cases}

\]

More text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should consider using an `align` (or similar) environment ;-)

Answer (score 1):

One can replace `\[` with `\par\medskip\(` and replace `\]` with `\)\par\medskip`.  Not necessary in this case, but one may also need a `\displaystyle` added after the `\(`.  Depending on your value of `\parindent`, a `\noindent` may also be needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, array}
\begin{document}
$M( \langle U_1, \dots, U_n \rangle ) \to \langle Y_1, \dots, Y_n \rangle $ where
\par\medskip\(
Y_i = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }  U_i \in \Sigma \\
0 & \text{if }  U_i \notin \Sigma \\
\end{cases}
\)\par\medskip
More text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `flalign` environment and put every equation between two `&`. Add `\nonumber` or `\notag` if you don't want your equations numbered.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2]

    \begin{flalign} 
        &M( \langle U_1, \dots, U_n \rangle ) \to \langle Y_1, \dots, Y_n \rangle \qquad \text{where} & \nonumber \\ 
        &Y_i = \begin{cases}
            1 & \text{if }  U_i \in \Sigma \\
            0 & \text{if }  U_i \notin \Sigma \\
        \end{cases} & \nonumber
    \end{flalign}

    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]